# avoiding error from pd.to_datetime in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe more than 100 mln rows.  In that I have a date columns, unfortunately have improper formatted (mixed) date strings.

Now I did convert it to datetime by:

```
df['TRX_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TRX_DATE'],coerce=True)
# without any error
# Now i want to calculate week day from that date columns
df['day_type'] = [x.strftime('%A') for x in d['TRX_DATE']]
###ValueError: month out of range
```

If it would a single field I can manage with dateutil parser. But in this case I am getting out of idea, how to handle that.

Just intersted, if the week conversion line can have something like if anything getting out of range place a default...

Have the idea but as a newbie. Don't have that much experience to do that.

It would be great help if someone can give a code line to handle that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you can parse [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` and then use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for converting to [weekday as locale’s full name](http://strftime.org/):

```
print df
              TRX_DATE  some value
0  2010-08-15 13:00:00      27.065
1  2010-08-16 13:10:00      25.610
2  2010-08-17 02:30:00      17.000
3  2010-06-18 02:40:00      17.015
4  2010-18-19 02:50:00      16.910

df['TRX_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TRX_DATE'],errors='coerce')

df['day_type'] = df['TRX_DATE'].dt.strftime('%A')
print df
             TRX_DATE  some value day_type
0 2010-08-15 13:00:00      27.065   Sunday
1 2010-08-16 13:10:00      25.610   Monday
2 2010-08-17 02:30:00      17.000  Tuesday
3 2010-06-18 02:40:00      17.015   Friday
4                 NaT      16.910      NaT
```

Comment: @jezrael- Already tried that..getting same error...i know some dataissue is there.but identifying the flaws from such a huge data  is difficult for me...so need to avoid the error anyhow

Comment: What is version of your `pandas`? `print pd.show_versions()` Is possible share data?

Comment: Hmmm, but now the last version of `pandas` is `0.18.0`. Is possible update `pandas`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109433/discussion-between-jezrael-and-satya).

Comment: what does Nat mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
[x.strftime('%A') for x in df['TRX_DATE'] if not isinstance(x, pandas.tslib.NaTType)]
```