# How to find place name in large file with regex python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

So I'm tring to find exact words from country.txt file which is define name of places with a descriptions file below:

**here is the example of country.txt**

```
Pic de Font Blanca
Roc Mélé
Pic des Langounelles
Pic de les Abelletes
Estany de les Abelletes
Port Vieux de la Coume d’Ose
Port de la Cabanette
Port Dret
Costa de Xurius
Font de la Xona
```

**and here is a description.csv**
[description file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQgCs.png)

Descriptions file is a list of data that contains titles and descriptions of the article. What I am trying to do is to find exact words of place name from descriptions file with country.txt file

**code.py**

```
import csv
import time
import re

allCities = open('country.txt', encoding="utf8").readlines()
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-(%H-%M-%S)")

with open('description.csv') as descriptions,open('desc_place7---' + str(timestr) + '.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as output:
    descriptions_reader = csv.DictReader(descriptions)
    fieldnames = ['title', 'description', 'place']
    output_writer = csv.DictWriter(output, delimiter='|', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    output_writer.writeheader()
    line=0
    pattern = r'|'.join(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(city.strip())) for city in sorted(allCities, key=len, reverse=True))

    for eachRow in descriptions_reader:
        title = eachRow['row']
        description = eachRow['desc']
        citiesFound = set()
        found = re.findall(pattern, description, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
        citiesFound.update(found)
        if len(citiesFound)==0:
            output_writer.writerow({'title': title, 'description': description, 'place': " - "})

        else:
            output_writer.writerow({'title': title, 'description': description, 'place': " , ".join(citiesFound)})
        line += 1
        print(line)
```

**expected output**:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfXrt.png)

But because country.txt(185.94MB) is a large file, so my code can't fully run. It makes my laptop freeze.
Is there a good way to handle this? I think its also because of the pattern line I have makes low performance but I also need a regex to find exact words

Comment: Hi, why are you sorting `allCitices`?

Comment: which of these files is the smallest?

Comment: @DavidDr90 If there are potential matches like "New York" and "New York City" - the longer candidate must appear first in the pattern.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz descriptions.csv file

Comment: @drowsyone so first find all "New York" cantitates and then sort them. Don't sort ~190MB file

Comment: @DavidDr90 I see, but I also try to not using sorting allCities and still got this problem

Comment: @drowsyone and you shouldn't be reading a whole 190 MB file in memory (`allCities` list / `pattern` string). You should structure your code in such a way that cities are read line by line and not saved into memory.

Comment: @drowsyone can you explain what are you trying to get in the `pattern` variable?

Comment: @DavidDr90 that line is appending every city in `allCities` list into a string separated by `|`.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz Would you like to help me how to do that? cause I have no idea how to start. Thanks in advance

Comment: @drowsyone you can use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/how-can-i-read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-into

Comment: @DavidDr90 Im trying to find exact words of description.csv file that match with country.txt. I want my code return title,descriptions and also place based of country.txt

Comment: @drowsyone I'm missing some varible in your code. What is `m` in line: `found = re.findall(pattern, m, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)`?

Comment: Oh im sorry, its `description`

Comment: @drowsyone I answered your question with some basic implementation. enjoy!

Comment: As it has not been asked before: Why do you need an image as output?

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz i already tried using head and tail but it seems like no difference, my code still running so slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a first implementation for your problem, you need to take and improve it to your specific needs.

First save all your `descriptions` to a `pandas` `DataFrame` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
descriptions = pd.read_csv('description.csv')
```

Then **Do not read all file lines to memory**. You can read the `country` file line by line and look for matches in the `descriptions` data. Use the following:

```
 with open('country.txt', encoding="utf8") as cities_file, open('desc_place7---' + str(timestr) + '.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as output:
    fieldnames = ['title', 'description', 'place']
    output_writer = csv.DictWriter(output, delimiter='|', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    output_writer.writeheader()
    line = 0        
    for city in cities_file:
        pattern = r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(city.strip())
        for index, row in descriptions.iterrows():
            title = row['row']
            description = row['desc']
            citiesFound = set()            
            found = re.findall(pattern, description, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
            citiesFound.update(found)
            if len(citiesFound)==0:
                output_writer.writerow({'title': title, 'description': description, 'place': " - "})
            else:
                output_writer.writerow({'title': title, 'description': description, 'place': " , ".join(citiesFound)})
            line += 1
            print(line)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. It works, but what if I want `descriptions` to just only one time, not iterate until it get a place name?

Comment: @drowsyone you can see this answer [how to filter rows in pandas by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325182/how-to-filter-rows-in-pandas-by-regex)  or [searching matching string pattern from dataframe column in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740680/searching-matching-string-pattern-from-dataframe-column-in-python-pandas) it will iterate for you

Comment: I dont want iterate. I mean how to join all the name place of each row of article. Not iterate all row based on name place

Comment: Hey I think your code still can't run for large file